# Connection string problem when deploying ASP.NET MVC website to PLESK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-config, connection-string, plesk

I'm going through a basic tutorial for ASP.NET MVC based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/) [Microsoft Help document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/). The app displays books and authors from a database and allows for CRUD operations on that data.  Everything is working fine on my machine when I run locally developing with Visual Studio 2017. But when I try to to deploy to my PLESK hosted website I'm having problems.  I recreated (from scratch) a MySQL database designed to exactly replicate the schema of local database and populated it with sample values. When the page loads, I'm getting a long hang and ultimately a 500 error after it tries unsuccessfully to connect to the database.

This is the connection string that is working locally:

`<add name="BookServiceContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=BookServiceContext-20200803155333; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|BookServiceContext-20200803155333.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

And here's the connectionStrings part of the remote web.config:

`<add name="BookServiceContext" connectionString="Server=###.##.###.##;Database=BookServiceContext;Uid=myPLESKUserIDAssociatedWithDatabase;Pwd=PasswordForTheUser;multipleactiveresultsets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Perhaps I have the syntax wrong or am missing a setting in PLESK (I was trying to use a sample from ConnectionStrings.com and haven't set up a DB in PLESK before).

[image]

Comment: make sure that asp.net is installed on the server... I think Plesk has a tool for that... then check this page for different connection strings (it helped me quite a bit when I was trying to hack out mine for Windows Server 2016 anyway):  https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2016/

Comment: also check your root folder to see if you have an "appsettings" file. Or more than 1... in my case "appsettings.production.json" was the one actually being used...